# ASM ByteCode - override visitLine() method

Tags: java, java-bytecode-asm

The visitLine() method of the ASM bytecode manipulation framework visits each line of the source code from which it was compiled.

If I have a line broken down in the source code like

```
Line 45:   ArrayList<Integer> test = new ArrayList<
Line 46:                                 Integer>();
```

Then it shows both 45 and 46. Is there a way to override it so that it shows this execution as just Line 45?

Comment: In bytecode it will be just one line

Comment: @esin88   Okay. I have overridden the visitLine method to print all the lines visited. And it shows both 45 and 46. Is that expected?

Comment: If in your source code you have a line break with code on both lines that needs to be compiled to opcodes, this will be retained in the bytecode. This is due to bytecode storing the lines in a table attribute that associates ranges of opcodes to line numbers. ASM simplifies the whole process though.

Comment: *Why*? Where’s the relevance of that information? The fact that you want to “override visitLine() method” suggests that there is another visitor whose behavior you want to alter. What kind of visitor is it and what does it do with that information? That looks much like an [xy problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/66378/242352).

Answer (score 1):

ASM adds all line information that is added by the Jaca compiler. If you want to drop a line, you would need to filter such lines yourself. For example, you could check if a line does not include an instruction, you could suppress the call to any underlying method visitor.

Comment: Okay. Thanks for your suggestion. I will try that.